# How to I control 16 images on 16 frames?

Tags: flash-cs5, flash-cs4, flash-cs6, flash-cs5.5

I have a fla with 16 frames, and in each frame there is a png from the library.

I have a script that publishes each frame in the fla as an individual png.

What I am doing now is manually modify each image on each frame so that it fits unpon a particular setting of scale and x/y positioning.

The purpose of this fla is take 16 rendered frames from a 3d program and scale/center/whatever them to my liking.

My problem is that I have to MANUALLY do it for 16 frames and would like some advice on how to simplify this process.

Note that each individual set has different output for width and height which makes me have to reposition and rescale the 16 frames.

I do want/have to do it at least once so I fit it to my liking, but the rest 15, something automated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turn each png into a Sprite or MovieClip by aelecting it on the stage and pressing F8. Then give it an instance name in the Properties panel. Now you can address each of these objects in your code, and programaticaly change each instance's position, scale, whatever.